# how to increase Finder font size larger than 16 point in mavericks

Tags: finder

OS X Mavericks seems to only allow for font sizes up to 16 point, which at a high resolution on a 27" iMac when I've been sitting across the room watching a movie, is not nearly large enough.

How can I increase past 16 point?  I've tried TinkerTool to no avail, and editing com.apple.plist also to no avail.  Is there any way to overcome this seemingly arbitrary limit?

Comment: Have you looked in the Accessibility settings?

Comment: Yes, I'm not looking to zoom the screen - I could just reduce the resolution if that was acceptable.  I want to increase the font size and nothing else.